# A referenced assembly was compiled using a newer version of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll

Tags: .net-5

I try-converted a windows form app to .NET 5 and I was able to build and run it last week. Now, it has an error building.

> NETSDK1148    A referenced assembly was compiled using a newer version of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll. Please update to a newer .NET SDK in order to reference this assembly.   APP C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Windows.targets

Target framework for the csproj is `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>`

I'm unsure what to change/update. Error is a little vague.

Comment: Looks like it is thrown here https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/15430/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` from the project fixed this issue. See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16360